# Jquery toggle not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, hide, toggle

i am trying to get jquery to hide this div and for some reason it is not working what am i doing wrong

http://stat-me.com/jq.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
#one{
    border:3px solid #00F;
    width:50%;
}
#hideme{
    border:3px solid #00F;
    width:50%;
    display:none;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../_root/js/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">



$("#one").click(function () {
$("#hideme").toggle();
});

</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="one">
<a href="#">hello</a>
</div>

<div id="hideme">
hi
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to:

1. Use [document.ready](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$%28document%29.ready%28%29)
2. Select the anchor *underneath* the #one div, not the div itself

So it should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#one a").click(function() {
    $("#hideme").toggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: Both gotchas I've encountered maaaany times :)

Answer (score 2):

Your not wrapping your javascript in `$(document).ready(function(){})` etc do jQuery is trying to find an element that doesn't exist yet!

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same situation while using ajax and applied this solution.
Write javascript:void(0); instead of a '#' in href value. this prevents you to add '#' in url.
use .live() when using in ajax mode. in .toggle(), pass argument as effect like 'Drop', 'slide' etc, more at http://jqueryui.com/toggle/.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#one a').live('click', function(){
            $('#hideme').toggle('Drop');
            return false;
         });
     });
```

Applying return false; at last preventing me to reload the page.

Answered just for knowledge.