# jQuery toggle doesn't work in my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to toggle a div with jQuery toggle function.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#removeSongButton").click(function () {
    $("#radioButton1").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <asp:Button runat="server" ID="removeSongButton" Text="remove song"  />
</div>

<div id="radioButton1">
  <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="radioButton">
    <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="3" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
  </asp:RadioButtonList  >         
</div>
```

when i click the "removeSongButton" the div togעle up and immediately toggle down. i think maybe the page reload.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery toggle not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708086/jquery-toggle-not-working)

Comment: don't tell asp to run it on server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, its the reload.
If the onliest thing you want to do by button-click is to toggle then add an preventDefault like this. Or are there other events you want to trigger by the button-click?

```
$("#removeSongButton").click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#radioButton1").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `div#radioButton1`as your selector. I've created a super simple **jsbin** 
http://jsbin.com/rudocofowu/edit?html,output

---

If that doesn't help, then I would start with removing `toggle()` and try to use just `slideUp()` or `slideDown()` from jQuery just to isolate which one is messing up.

Comment: ID's are unique...putting a tagname in front is less efficient than just using the ID. Changing the selector won;t change behavior OP has either

Comment: @charlietfl It's not less efficient. If anything, it's more efficient because you are getting more specific with what you're selecting. Have you tried using .slideUp() or .slideDown()?

Comment: you don't understand dom searches then. An ID is absolute and does not require a search of multiple nodes in dom. The dom tracks ID's

Comment: @charlietfl This could hep out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497802/how-to-stop-asp-net-from-changing-ids-in-order-to-use-jquery